# Free GIS software for orthorectification?

Tags: open-source-gis, remote-sensing

Could someone recommend a free and/or open source GIS application that can orthorectify map images?

Answer (score 23):

For orthorectification:

In [GRASS](http://grass.osgeo.org/) see [i.ortho.photo](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/i.ortho.photo.html).
In [OSSIM](http://www.ossim.org/OSSIM/OSSIM_Home.html), see [OSSIMOrthos.pdf](http://download.osgeo.org/ossim/docs/pdfs/)

For georeferencing:

In [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/), use the Georeferencer plugin, p 223 of the [user guide](http://download.osgeo.org/qgis/doc/manual/qgis-1.8.0_user_guide_en.pdf).
There is even an online tool for georeferencing at http://www.georeferencer.org/

Comment: And just remember that you will need an elevation datasets such as a DEM to rectify the imagery to.

Answer (score 7):

INPE in Brazil ([National Institute of Spatial Research](http://www.dgi.inpe.br/)) has an software called Marlin used for some raster data processing. It's known Marlin can orthorectify, tough I don't know how to proceed. But it's free.INPE also develops the SPRING software. It a GIS suite that can orthorectify and it's free as well.

But unfortunately, those two softwares are not open-source.

Answer (score 4):

Qgis or Grass or uDIG ... For each of these software look into the plugins and 3rd party plugins as well

Comment: Note that only GRASS GIS supports it, in this suggestion it is used as extension in QGIS or uDIG.

Answer (score 4):

Orfeo Toolbox has some tools for orthorectification, mainly for satellite images (using the RPC information), and it is an open source image processing library. It uses on OSSIM. It can be embedded in QGIS, but it has its own GUI (Monteverdi) as well as command line applications.