# GeoTIFF file creation from .Tiff file

Tags: google-earth, export, geotiff-tiff

I'm working on some software that displays a map, like this:

![enter image description here][1]

I also have some export functions which exports the about image as `.bmp/.Tiff/.Jpg/.PNG/.Wmf/.SVG`

This is .TIFF export:

![enter image description here][2]

Now I also have to export it as `GeoTiff`. The software I am working on is in `Delphi 7`.

**information**

I have come across this [steps to creating a geotiff](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/17039/6758), but since I am new to GeoTIFF, I am stuck after the first point.

**question**

Is it possible to convert the `.TIFF` file to `.geotiff`?

**what I have tried**

[remotesensing geotiff](http://www.remotesensing.org/geotiff/geotifcp.html)

[how to write geotiff files in delphi possibly-compressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480527/how-to-write-geotiff-files-in-delphi-possibly-compressed)

but I can't figure out how to create the meta data for the tiff to create the GeoTIFF

Comment: from your mapdisplay, is it possible to obtain the below information?
1.lat/long values of the four corners and center
2.Pixel size(in x and y directions) in mapdisplay

Comment: @vinayan : `1.lat/long values of the four corners and center ` this is possible... `2.Pixel size(in x and y directions) in mapdisplay` i didnt get you... pixel size as in?

Comment: `2.Pixel size(in x and y directions) in mapdisplay` you mean pixel size of the each point on the map?

Comment: would you consider marking any of the below as answers if your problem is solved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a little bit of information which might help you in your task.
First you may need to download [FWTools](http://fwtools.maptools.org/) inorder to use geotifcp and listgeo.

Create a TIFF File(You already did it..) Let us call it `initialtif.tif`

find the image width and height(from where you saved it).
[image: Image Width and Height]

```
imageWidth = 1016
imageHeight = 551
```

Create a World File for our initialtif.tif using the below parameters.

From Wiki, the World File is defined as below. Refer below image for details. mapWidth and mapHeight are to be measured from your map application.

```
Line 1: A: pixel size in the x-direction in map units/pixel = mapWidth/imageWidth
Line 2: D: rotation about y-axis = 0
Line 3: B: rotation about x-axis = 0
Line 4: E: pixel size in the y-direction in map units, almost always negative[3] = -mapHeight/imageHeight
Line 5: C: x-coordinate of the center of the upper left pixel = C
Line 6: F: y-coordinate of the center of the upper left pixel = F
```

Enter these 6 numbers on a text file and save as `initialtif.tfw`

[image: World File Details]

Get a GeoTiff(say reference.tif) in the same Coordinate System/projection. Get one from your friends or create it yourself using Qgis/Arcgis..

extract metadata from GeoTiff using `listgeo` command(In Windows..)

```
listgeo -proj4 reference.tif >metadata.txt
```

Create GeoTiff using `geotifcp` command

```
geotifcp -g metadata.txt -e forWorld.TFwx forWorld.TIF finaltiff.tif
```

Comment: +1, awesomely simple explanation. but still i can get `Line 1: A: pixel size in the x-direction in map units/pixel = mapWidth/imageWidth` how to get it?

Comment: is it ? `13141548/551` in case of your example

Comment: @PresleyDias - It will be (13141548/1016)..width divided by width..

Answer (score 5):

The world file is VERY simple and this is most of the meta data you need to convert your .tif to a geotif.  While we're on the subject, in most GIS applications, if you have a world-file, you don't need to convert to geotiff or JP2000 or any other format where the geotocation information is embedded.  The GIS will look for and read the world file.

A world file has a similar extension as the image format except the last letter is  a 'w'.  So the world file for a tiff is '.tfw', for a '.bmp' it is '.bpw', for a '.jpg' it is '.jpw' and so on.

A good description of the world-file can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file).  From that and the image dimensions, you should be able to write your own world file by hand.  For example, below is a world file for a random tiff off my hard-drive.  In my case the units are meters.  The bits in brackes are my annotations:

```
2.50  (pixel size in the x-direction in map units)
0.00  (rotation about y-axis)
0.00  (rotation about y-axis)
-2.50  (pixel size in the y-direction in map units)
450001.250  (x-coordinate of the center of the upper left pixel)
1209998.750  (y-coordinate of the center of the upper left pixel)
```

That's it!

Alternatively you could make a geotiff in one step using GDAL (see [gdalwarp](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html)).  You effectively are pluging in all this information into the command-line parameters plus you can set the out-going projection too.  This would be my preference to the four-step process described in the link.  You will note from the documentation that 'geotiff' is the default output format, so you don't even have to specify it!

Comment: +1,ok, nice explanation, but how to get the `2.50  (pixel size in the x-direction in map units)` pixel size?

Comment: Divide the width of the image in realworld units by the number of pixels to get meters per pixel for each direction.  You should know the width in real-world units from when you create the image and get the image dimensions in pixels from the image file's properties.

Comment: The problem with world files is that they don't contain full spatial reference information - datums, projections etc. So they are not trully equivalent to full GeoTIFF metadata.