# Mass downloading Google Earth historical imagery

Tags: google-earth, landsat, historical-imagery

I've been working with the historical imagery in Google Earth and I'm wondering if there's an easy way to download the geoTIFFs for my study area. It doesn't seem possible from Google Earth itself.

Is there a website where I drag a box around/upload a polygon of my study area and be able to download geoTIFFs of all the historical satellite images for that area in one zipped file?

Comment: it is possible in a long winded way https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16986/steps-to-creating-a-geotiff  but be aware of the terms and conditions.

Answer (score 1):

For downloading raw data, I would rather suggest that you use specific data provider. The longest historical time series of high resolution data, as far as I know, is Landsat. So you can use [EarthExplorer](https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/), draw a box and define the time period that you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Google Earth Engine, as it provides a database for both Landsat and Sentinel images.

Landsat - https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/landsat

Sentinel - https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/sentinel