# Batch rectifying 200+ historic aerial images?

Tags: georeferencing, batch, aerial-photography, software-recommendations, orthorectification

I have acquired historic aerial imagery for the surrounding towns, circa 1954, and the images have no georeference.

I am looking for software to help me batch-rectify the 200+ images. I have current orthophotos, DEMs, and other vector information for the area.

Comment: Firstly it is going to be hard to georeference unknown locations you need at least 3 points of known locations to reference to. Older Aerials Photographs are likely to require some pre-processing to recifiy distortion in the images (len correction etc). see http://3dkap.aircatcher.com/index.php?id=147

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://mapwarper.net . Assuming they're all the same extent you can use its "align" tool to match your georeferencing points for multiple images

Answer (score 0):

Once you get a known local coordinate of the location, you can use ERDAS' AutoSync or ENVI's Image Registration to aligned many historic imagery over orthophotos or Landsat where they have known local coordinate. It's not that hard to do that.

For example, I have had many of the ASTER that need to have the aligned over other imagery  because of the way the Earth moves and the satellite in space. That is where you want to use these software. I am not sure about the open-source ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can't automatically georeference imagery. You need to tie it into key points. Unless you have a coordinated bounding box for the image (which is kind of like a georeference any way).

If your images are georeferenced and you want to ortho-rectify (meaning, remove terrain distortions) then I think it will be a little tricky, but see [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9334/free-gis-software-that-can-orthorectify) for open source ways.

If you just want to georeference a bunch of images, you can do that in QGIS quite efficiently. Here's a [tutorial](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/advanced_georeferencing.html), though it doesn't look great. Since you've got existing imagery for the area, set up a QGIS workspace with that in it, so you've got some known points. Then load each image you want to georeference up in turn and use the georeferencer tool. It'll take time, but there's not automated way to do it.