# Open Source True Ortho Software

Tags: open-source-gis

My work does true ortho rectification.  We are looking to transition into a more open source company.  One of the processes we are looking to "open source" is true ortho.  Does anyone know of a software package (open source) that can perform true orthorectification.  Ideally, it would be a complete package, but it could be a series of libraries, tools, plugins, etc.

Thanks...

Reclarification:

A true ortho is similar, but different to a regular ortho.  With regular orthos you will have building lean.  A true ortho is a process to remove the lean, and "stand-up" the buildings.  The following is an explanation: http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/1001/standup.html

Because of this, I do not believe this is a duplicated question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [free GIS software that can orthorectify?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9334/free-gis-software-that-can-orthorectify)

Comment: MapKnitter is a potential https://github.com/jywarren/mapknitter

Comment: Might be worth clarifying what you mean by true ortho as opposed to geo-rectify (or false ortho, if there is such a thing:-)). Not everyone understands the differences.

Comment: If the linked possible duplicate is not really a duplicate, perhaps because the solutions there don't do "true" rectification, please explain how your question is different. Thanks :)

Comment: No I do not believe this is the same, as true ortho is much different.  Just because you can ortho something, it doesn't mean you can true ortho.  A shapefile and a postgis table can have geometry and attributes, but they are not the same thing, nor does all software interact with them.

Comment: @BradHards, true orthorectification involves getting an aerial image direct from an aircraft and removing distortion that is introduced by terrain, usually with the use of a DTM/DEM. Link: http://www.satimagingcorp.com/svc/orthorectification.html

Comment: @alexgleith: it doesn't need to be from an aircraft. I believe I understand it, but I'm not sure that understanding it universal.

Comment: @BradHards, sure, it doesn't need to be from an aircraft. I reckon that the distortion from relief is less impactful with satellite imagery, but still present, sure.