# Aerial mosaic of thermography

Tags: image-mosaic, aerial-photography, orthophoto, orthorectification

I have a large set of aerial images (thermography) some of them are very tilted due to the airplane turning. I want to merge all the images into a unique orthorectified image. I have not the GPS information but I know the place where the termography was taken. Which is the best way to proceed? Is there any free software available?
 I have been trying Microsof ICE but the results are very distorted.

Comment: If you know the place where the image was taken then you can use google earth to find that location and extract coordinates and use them to rectify the images.

Comment: Perhaps the following post will help you select open-source orthrectification software: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/9334/8104