# Orthorectify large set aerial images

Tags: georeferencing, image, aerial-photography, orthorectification

I have a large set of images that I want to stitch the together and orthorectify. They have been taken from a small aircraft. The camera of the aircraft is tilted, thereby, although gps data is available, the image position and the gps position are different. I have tried some software such as Microsoft ICE and PTgui with no luck.

How could I proceed?

Comment: Please don't ask [the same question twice](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/179851/aerial-mosaic-of-thermography).

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Rather than open a new question, it is preferred to edit your original one to add relevant details and improve the post. Also, it appears that you have created two accounts--please follow these instructions to merge them: http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts.